# Does a step-up power converter cause move volts but less amps?

Tags: voltage, converter

I have a 5v 10,400mAH battery. I'm wondering if it would be possible to power my laptop charger with this. The laptop charger is 20v 3.25a. Is this possible? If I use a step-up voltage converter, won't it drop the amps?

Comment: well the laptop charger plugins into ac and it converts 110 ac into 20v 3.25a dc

Comment: Short version, YES. You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options:

1. An inverter that converts 5v DC to 110v AC. But they don't exist.
2. Convert 5v to 20v, but you would need to have a very well regulated step-up converter, otherwise you'll kill your laptop. Also, you may have trouble finding one that is capable of outputting over 3 amps.
3. Step-up converter from 5v to 12v, then use a 12v DC to 110v AC inverter. But you may have trouble finding a 5v-12v inverter that can supply enough power (watts) or current (amps)

The way to calculate amps and volts, is by this simple formula:

P = I V

or in English, Power = Current (amps) x Volts

So if you have a car battery, say, 12 volts, and you want to power a laptop, 110v, 1 amp, you can calculate the power of the laptop, and from that, work out the minimum current that would be drawn from the 12v battery:

Laptop power = 110 x 1 = 110 watts.

Substitute that into the same formula for the battery:
P = I V
110 = I x 12
Therefore I = 110 / 12

So the car battery would need to supply 9.1666 amps to the inverter to power the laptop.

But there would be inefficiencies - the inverter would be at least 10% inefficient. And the same goes for the laptop power supply.

So to answer your question, yes - if a step-up converter doubles the voltage, then it can only output half the amps. (Or consume twice as many amps. Same thing)

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: My answer includes the DC to DC option. I added the AC option because it's more practical: more easily available components. Also, bypassing the laptop PSU would be asking for problems, they are sensitive devices.The laptop PSUs are tailored precisely for that laptop, and include a whole host of filters and so on to protect it.

Comment: okay well this answers my question. This battery has a 5v 2a output. to get 20v would make it 20v .5a. So its impossible to have 3.5 a. and 20v at the same time. So yea thanks for answering my question.

Comment: I removed downvote after your edits and expanded answer, although there is nothing "magical" about Laptops versus other power supply design target loads. Using an inverter can be just as hazardous is designed or applied improperly.

Comment: A cheap 20v DC PSU may not handle full current draw without unacceptable ripple or voltage drop, among other things. For the novice, I would not recommend just trying any old 20v DC supply on the laptop. That is really the point.

Comment: A cheap inverter may produce psuedo-sine waves with high-frequency components that can damage the converter and charger circuitry and "may not handle full current draw without unacceptable ripple or voltage drop" -- you see the problem here is bad design/application, not the architecture. The inverter will *always* be the worst solution ceteris paribus.

Comment: Fair point. Going out on a limb here then, my final point is that I'd argue that the laptop power supply would be designed with possible use in mind such as being run off supplies with waveforms as unhealthy as that of a cheap inverter.